# How to upload file with CEF?

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am using CefSharp but the question applies also for CEF C++

I have javascript application that you can use to edit/transform images. After you are done you want to upload the image to CEF and save it in database/filesystem.

Javascript code uploads the file using FormData API as multipart/form-data. I have custom ResourceHandler which is handling the request and trying to read the post data.

However in

`bool ProcessRequest(IRequest request, ICallback callback)`

`request.PostData.HasExcludedElements == true`

and file binary data is missing. I found those posts

https://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16625 
https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=14371

which describes the same problem. It seems this is not supported by CEF, however there is no workaround how to upload binary file.

How I am supposed to upload binary data (Blob) from Javascript to CEF?

Answer (score 1):

You can make an AJAX request to a fake URL like `http://grab-this-image.com/grabme.htm?savas=filename` and intercept it in (C++) `ClientHandler::OnBeforeResourceLoad()`

Grab the data then return RV_CANCEL to cancel the navigation.

Comment: That doesn't make sense? The binary data is not provided by CEF in first place. How to "grab the data" if not provided by CEF?

Comment: You said the data was available to JavaScript on the client.  Have JavaScript make an XmlHttpRequest that includes the data.  Your C# / C++ event handler then intercepts the data.  If that is not your situation then please edit your question to include more information.

Comment: `I have javascript application that you can use to edit/transform images.` - is this running on the client?  Does it have access to the image in memory?  If yes, try using XmlHttpRequest instead of a form.

Comment: I have the data in javascript but when I make XmlHttpRequest with the data, CefResourceHandler don't have the data in PostData property. Read the links other people explained the same problem.